# Is 1 hour layover enough in Dusseldorf?

Tags: layovers, dusseldorf

I have a flight from kayseri turkey to Paris France connecting through dusseldorf.
The first flight is Turkish airlines and the second is Air France. I have a european residency card and will only have hand luggage.
Do you think that 1h layover is enough to make the connection ? (Especially with Covid restrictions and vaccine documents checking)
Thank you in advance

Comment: Are these two separate bookings or  a single booking?

Answer (score 7):

This looks like two separate bookings (since Turkish is Star Alliance and Air France is Skyteam).

In this case I would say no. Don't book that.

You will enter the Schengen area in Düsseldorf which means you have to clear passport control in Düsseldorf. Covid rules are highly unpredictable, so you won't know until you get there. Last time I checked in with Air France (about 3 months ago), they did not allow online check in but you had to physically show up at the check in counter for a doc check.

Even if this is a single ticket, this feels tight but if you miss it, it's the airline's responsibility to get you to your final destination.

For separate tickets you are on your own and may have to buy a new (and very expensive) ticket on the fly.

Answer (score 4):

to answer my own question (late but at least it's answered).
I managed to get the flight but :

- i was the first one to disembark from the plane (had to ask a steward for this favor)
- ran between the different desks
- it was a mid week mid day flight between two little cities

so i would answer : no it's not enough and if you take a flight alike, you are gambling